# ActionBeanNotFoundException – invalid URLs

Tags: java, tomcat, hosting, stripes

I have a Java web application that runs on a Tomcat server in a production environment. The application which is built with the Stripes framework works fine but almost every day exceptions are logged in the catalina.log files. Here is, for example, one of the log messages:

```
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.ActionBeanNotFoundException: Could not locate an ActionBean that is bound to the URL [/admin/start/Welcome.action].
```

“/start/Welcome.action” is a valid URL but the URL “/admin/start/Welcome.action” is not present anywhere in my project files. I have no idea where it originates from.

Here are other invalid URLs that are also listed in the log files:

```
/wordpress/start/Welcome.action
/downloader/start/Welcome.action
/manager/start/Welcome.action
/admin/content/sitetree/start/Welcome.action
```

These URLs do not exist and have never existed in my application. Apart from them there is another group of ActionBeanNotFoundException messages about URLs that have once existed in the application but they do not any more.

Do you have an explanation of this? I asked this question to my hosting provider but they were unable to answer me. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities: Either some component in your web application generates such a URL - just in esoteric places that people rarely click on. If your application is available on the internet, those links in esoteric places might provide a place for the google bot (or any other bot for that matter) to try what's available in those locations, thus requesting the nonexistent URL. You don't need to go to bots for that matter, some browsers prefetch some URLs before you click.

Another option would be internet background chatter - various computers worldwide try to randomly identify vulnerable systems by just requesting well-known pages in order to find security holes in old software. The URLs that you mention (ending in `.action`) don't look like those though.